# How to run Servlet based website in desktop application

Tags: java, html, url, servlets, desktop-application

I searched a lot but did not find any problem solving answer. I want to run servlet based website in desktop application using java but i am unable to do it. Is there any way to view static response in desktop application.

Comment: Main problem in this approach is that for any modern web page you need to embed native web browser into your app.

Comment: does java provides native web browser?

Comment: No. It doesn't. You probably can find some lib that do this, but in my opinion it is simply poor choice of platform for this task. With `.Net`, for example, it will be much easier.

Comment: @talex  Is is possible to use .Net and java both. .Net for native web browser and java for desktop application ?

Comment: Yes. But you shouldn't. It will be no easier than embed native web browser into java desktop app. If you already have servlet app I suggest you to write `.Net` desktop app that will start java web container in background and then show embedded browser.